# Find unknown contravariantly typed service at runtime using IOC

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inversion-of-control, solid-principles

I have a requirement where given an object of an unknown type, I need to return a user friendly string which describes the object. I realise I could just override the ToString method, but I can't always gurantee that these objects will be mine.

Therefore, given the classes below:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Title { get { return "Foo title"; } }
}
public class Bar
{
    public string Name { get { return "Foo name"; } }
}
```

I would like to be able to output the title property value for the Foo object and the Name property value for the Bar object.

In order to make this happen, I've created this interface:

```
public interface ITypeStringFormattingService<in T>
{
    string FormatValue(T value);
}
```

And this class:

```
public class FooStringFormattingService : ITypeStringFormattingService<Foo>
{
    public string FormatValue(Foo value)
    {
        return value.Title;
    }
}
```

I can therefore do:

```
ITypeStringFormattingService<Foo> formatter = new FooStringFormattingService();
string s = formatter.FormatValue(new Foo()); // Will output "Foo title"
```

My issue is, since I don't know the type of the object until runtime, how do I obtain the correct generically typed TypeStringFormattingService given some object?

My (simplified) requirement is something like this:

```
object unknownObject = ExternalObject.GetRandomObject();
string friendlyString = new FormattingService().FormatValue(unknownObject); // Output expected string
```

I would usually solve this by injecting an array of my services (using castle windsor) into a factory/strategy class, and then filtering them by some method to find the service I require. However, since this is a contravariant generic (see "in" keyword), I don't think this is possible? Am I missing something, or should my classes be structured differently for the situation I'm tackling?

So far, I've only been able to get past this using casting (which doesn't feel correct), service locator, or newing up each of the services in a factory (which doesn't make use of IOC).

Example fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nxwaJR
Any code can be changed except "ExternalObject" and ideally the object types.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that illustrates how this can be achieved. It contains:

- Classes Foo and Bar to be formatted.
- Generic interface ITypeStringFormattingService<> definition for implementing formatters.
- Two implementations of that interface for formatting Foo and Bar objects.
- (here starts the interesting part) Universal formatter that aggregates other formatters and does some boilerplate stuff in one place. In order to function it needs all other formatters to be injected into it somehow. I'm unfamiliar with Castle Windsor DI container (actually I see it for the first time), so maybe I'm missing something or doing something wrong, but I haven't found a better way of doing it in 10 minutes other than injecting DI container and resolving them dynamically by parameter type. However, this is not the point of the answer.
- Container accessor for Castle.Windsor DI container. To me, this is a bit odd way of implementing it, but I haven't found other way to inject DI container in the service. Autofac provides a built-in way of doing that.

If anyone knows how to register those types better - you're welcome to leave your comments. As I said I'm unfamiliar with Castle Windsor.

The main part is pretty straightforward. When we call FormatValue() on the universal formatter it is first building the closed generic type of interface that should be formatting this particular type of object. Then, we're trying to resolve this type from DI container. After resolving proper formatter, we're calling its FormatValue() method. The special thing about it is using "dynamic" keyword for variable holding formatter and as a cast of the object. It is done this way because we cannot specify any other type for formatter. We will know its real type only at runtime, and since it is generic we cannot cast it to any other type based on the same generic as well. Using "dynamic" we just let DLR determine proper method to call on the particular formatter using the particular type of parameter. Dynamics have its own overhead related to reflection, but this is not the point of the answer as well and it can be optimized.

```
using System;
using Castle.MicroKernel.Registration;
using Castle.Windsor;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Foo
    {
        public string Title => "Foo title";
    }
    public class Bar
    {
        public string Name => "Foo name";
    }

    public interface ITypeStringFormattingService<in T>
    {
        string FormatValue(T value);
    }

    public class FooStringFormattingService : ITypeStringFormattingService<Foo>
    {
        public string FormatValue(Foo value)
        {
            return value.Title;
        }
    }

    public class BarStringFormattingService : ITypeStringFormattingService<Bar>
    {
        public string FormatValue(Bar value)
        {
            return value.Name;
        }
    }

    public class UniversalFormatter : ITypeStringFormattingService<object>
    {
        private readonly IWindsorContainer _container;

        public UniversalFormatter(IContainerAccessor container)
        {
            _container = container.Container;
        }
        public string FormatValue(object value)
        {
            dynamic formatter = _container.Resolve(typeof(ITypeStringFormattingService<>).MakeGenericType(value.GetType()));
            return formatter.FormatValue((dynamic) value);
        }
    }

    public class ContainerAccessor : IContainerAccessor
    {
        public ContainerAccessor(IWindsorContainer container)
        {
            Container = container;
        }

        public IWindsorContainer Container { get; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();

            container.Register(Component.For<IContainerAccessor>().Instance(new ContainerAccessor(container)));
            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ITypeStringFormattingService<Foo>)).ImplementedBy<FooStringFormattingService>());
            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ITypeStringFormattingService<Bar>)).ImplementedBy<BarStringFormattingService>());
            container.Register(Component.For(typeof(ITypeStringFormattingService<object>)).ImplementedBy<UniversalFormatter>());

            // Resolving

            var formatter = container.Resolve<ITypeStringFormattingService<object>>();

            object obj = new Bar();
            Console.WriteLine(formatter.FormatValue(obj));

            obj = new Foo();
            Console.WriteLine(formatter.FormatValue(obj));
        }
    }
}
```